# I can't receive notifications when screen is lock

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

I'm working with Firebase to send Push notification. When I have the app minimized and the screen lock and Data network on 3G, and batery at 90%, I can't receive notifications. I need to receive notifications while the screen is locked.

I noted this in the log at the moment to screen lock.

```
2019-06-13 16:40:35.901 2372-9542/? D/MC_BatteryStatsData: operate removing wakelock wake:com.exampleapp/.FCMListenerService
```

This is for a Moto C Android version 7.

I tried to add this permission to the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Disabled battery saver. It is in the menu `Settings -> Battery`.

And here is my `FCMInstanceIDListenerService.java`

```
public class FCMInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        MetodosRepo.setPreference(getBaseContext(), Globals.DEVICE_TOKEN, refreshedToken);
    }

}
```

And the `FMCListenerService.java`

```
public class FCMListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Log.e(_TAG, "onMessageReceived");
    }
}
```

I expect to receive a notification while the screen is locked.º

Comment: Without explanation it worked fine to next day. Maybe something was wrong with firebase service.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 8.0 they put a [background execution limit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) and hence you are not receiving the push notification when your application is in the background.

I would like to suggest implementing a [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) which will connect to your server to see if there is any pending notification and create the notification alert accordingly. Here is a sample project on how you can [implement your JobScheduler](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler).

However, Android takes care of the push notifications and you will receive a notification after 3-5 minutes I think (not almost instantly when the service is in the foreground).

Comment: I saw this when battery reaches 97% and it began work fine and fast. D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="wake:com.example.FCMListenerService", packageName=com.example, ownerUid=10226, ownerPid=9380, workSource=null